# Worklight Adapter based auth - Direct login

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to develope a simple hybrid app using an adapter based authentification.

All the examples I have found explain how to do it assuming that firstly we call a secured procedure to fire the authentication process.

I've been trying to develope a login calling directly to a "login adapter" to perform the authentication. I've tried using the "submitAdapterAuthentication" but the challenge handler is creating a infinite loop.

I did manage to make a login invoking the "login adapter" as a common procedure("WL.Client.invokeProcedure(...)"), but then I was not able to subscribe to a event source and I need PUSH notification functionality. I got always the next error:

```
Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server
```

Is it posible to authenticate against Worklight Server calling directly to a "login adapter" using Adapter Based Authentificaton? How?

I think the approach of a direct login call makes sense but I haven't found any official solution to it.

Comment: After almost to days stuck with this error, I found my silly error... I didn't notice that I had commented de "WL.Client.Connect" instruction... That was the reason of the "Cant's subscribe" error appearing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke authentication process explicitly, you can use `WL.Client.login(realm, options)` API provided by Worklight.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_login.html

Comment: I am calling the "login adapter" as a common procedure and it works, but I'll make a try wight the "WL.Client.login" function, it seems that it is the "correct" one.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a security test at the application level inside of application-descriptor.xml for each environment.
This will cause the app to ask for authentication immediately.

```
<iphone securityTest="nameOfMobileTest" bundleId="com.myApp" version="1.0>
      ....
</iphone>
<android securityTest="nameOfMobileTest" version="1.0">
      ....
</android>
```

Comment: But putting it on "common"? You mean maybe on the used environment... android, iphone, etc...

Comment: oops yes, changing it.

Comment: This would be a nice solution but I have one doubt. The authentication would fire in every start of the app, but what would happen when the app is opend from the backgorund?